# Moodle moodle_page::set_state : Invalid state error

Tags: moodle

In a page in a local plugin, I get error for $OUTPUT->header(); :

Coding error detected, it must be fixed by a programmer: Invalid state passed to moodle_page::set_state. We are in state 1 and state 1 was requested.

I have checked on google that the cause could be a second call to $OUTPUT->header();

But there is no second call.

Also, what is puzzling and surprising is that there is No error in all other pages, including, similar other local plugins, error is only for this local plugin page.

Also, I tried $OUTPUT->has_started() , it returns false.

Also, $PAGE->state is 0 , just before call to header.

Moodle version 2.8

Please help and guide.

Edit :

```
    require_once('../../config.php');

require_login();

global $CFG,$PAGE;

$PAGE->set_context(context_system::instance());
$PAGE->set_pagelayout('standard');
$PAGE->set_title('');
$PAGE->set_heading('');
$PAGE->set_url($CFG->wwwroot.'/local/tpmg/pending-manual.php');

if( ! $OUTPUT->has_started() )
{
    // echo $PAGE->state;exit;
    echo $OUTPUT->header();
}

if( isloggedin() )
{
    require_once('lib.php');

    $pmQuizzesObj = get_pm_quizzes();

    if( $pmQuizzesObj->pendingAttsCount )
    {
        $pmQuizzesArr = $pmQuizzesObj->quizzesArr; 

        echo get_string( 'tpmgpano','local_tpmg' ) . " : " . $pmQuizzesObj->pendingAttsCount . "<br/>";

        // Here goes table for Quizzes needing manual grading.
        $content = "<table class='mot_table'>";
        $content .= "<th>" . get_string( 'tpmgthead','local_tpmg' ) . "</th>";
        foreach( $pmQuizzesArr as  $key=>$currPmQuiz )
        {
            $tpmgQuizHref = $CFG->wwwroot . '/mod/quiz/report.php?id=' . $currPmQuiz->cmid . '&mode=grading';
            $content .= "<tr>";
            $content .= "<td>&nbsp;<a href=" . $tpmgQuizHref . ">" . $currPmQuiz->quizname . "</a></td>";
            $content .= "</tr>";
        }
        $content .= "</table>";

        echo $content;
    }
    else
    {
        echo get_string( 'tpmgnopm','local_tpmg' );
    }
}
else
{
    require_login();
}

echo $OUTPUT->footer();
```

Edit :
I have found out the page body, and possibly page header also, are getting printed twice. Please guide on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the page parameters ( $PAGE->set_* ) before calling the $OUTPUT->header();

Comment: Please reply :Yes i have done that. Here is my code  require_once('../../config.php');

 require_login();
 
 global $CFG,$PAGE;

 $PAGE->set_context(context_system::instance());
 $PAGE->set_pagelayout('standard');
 $PAGE->set_title(get_string( 'tpmgmenutitle','local_tpmg' ));
 $PAGE->set_heading(get_string( 'tpmgmenutitle','local_tpmg' ));
 $PAGE->set_url($CFG->wwwroot.'/local/tpmg/pending-manual.php');

 if( ! $OUTPUT->has_started() )
 {
  // echo $PAGE->state;exit;
  echo $OUTPUT->header();
 }

Comment: am i missing any parameter ? Please reply.

Comment: Please edit and update your code to your question for more clear. You have to make your question more clearly. I will try to check it out.